# Set equality comparison of union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was reading an introductory set theory book and came across the following question.
Give an example where $A \cup B = A \cup C$, But $B \ne C$.

I am lost. Any ideas?

Comment: Hint:  if B is any subset of A then A $\cup$ B = A.

Comment: Got it... Excellent.. Thank you. If A B and C are disjoint this case does not hold. am I right in saying that?

Comment: I believe you are.  If A, B, C are non-empty and have no pairwise intersections, then as you say, A $\cup$B ≠ A $\cup$ C.

Comment: Merci beaucoup ..l appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Take extreme examples: $A$ being a set containing $B$, $B$ non-empty, and $C$ empty.

Answer (score 0):

$A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ , $B=\{1,2,5\}$ and $C=\{3,5\}$.

> If $B\Delta C \subseteq A,$ then $A \cup B = A \cup C.$

Answer (score 0):

Not an example, but some theory around it.

$$A\cup B=A\cup C\iff B-A\subseteq C\subseteq A\cup B$$

This condition is satisfied by $C=B$.

If $B-A\neq A\cup B$ or equivalently $A\neq\varnothing$ there is more than one set $C$ that will satisfy this condition, so that you can find one that does not equalize $B$.